# Having trouble figureing out how to fetch the guild owner id from the new guild when it invites the bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so im trying to have the bot fetch the guild owner id from the guild that just joined so it can later compare to my database and see if they have a set role which will either lock or unlock certain commands. but no matter how i do it the owner id comes back as undefined and everything says "cannot read X of undefined." weather i try .users .guild etc etc

```js
/// adding a guild to the database upon invite
bot.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
    // Guild the user needs to have the role in
    let guildA = process.env.BOT_GUILD;
    console.log(guildA);

    // Role that the user needs
    let requiredRole = process.env.PAID_ROLE;
    console.log(requiredRole);

    // Member object of the user in guildA
    let member = guild.bot.users.fetch(guild.ownerID);
    console.log(member);

----------------------------

    i have also tried 

    // Member object of the user in guildA
    let member = bot.guild.ownerID;
    console.log(member);


    // Member object of the user in guildA
    let member = bot.guilds.cache.get(guild.ownerID).id;
    console.log(member);

    // Member object of the user in guildA
    let member = guilds.members.cache.get(guild.ownerID);
    console.log(member);

    etc etc etc
```

how can i properly fetch the guild owner id in this context? i feel like iv tried everything that works for everyone else at this point.

Comment: Both of the below answers work i cant mark both of them though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly but probably you did want to fetch the owner as a member. You can either use [`guild.owner`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=owner) or [`guild.members.fetch(ID)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members):

```js
bot.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
  // Guild the user needs to have the role in
  let guildA = process.env.BOT_GUILD;
  console.log(guildA);

  // Role that the user needs
  let requiredRole = process.env.PAID_ROLE;
  console.log(requiredRole);

  // fetch the guild owner as a member
  let member = await guild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);

  console.log(member);
});
```

Comment: thanks so much both of you. both of your answers gave the same information and from there i could figure out how to get the guild owner id properly. much love <3

Answer (score 2):

In the GuildCreate event, if you want to get the guild owner as a [user](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object, you have 2 choices. The Guild object contains the [ownerID](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=ownerID) property, which you already found out. But also the [owner](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=owner) property, which is a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object. I suggest checking if this owner property exists, which you can get the user from that by accessing GuildMember#user which will return the user object of the owner of that guild.

If the member doesn't exist, you will have to fetch the user. You can do this by **awaiting** the request when you fetch the user. As the fetch method returns a promise.

For example:

```
client.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
    const guildOwner = guild.owner ? guild.owner : await 
    guild.members.fetch(guild.ownerID);
    console.log(guildOwner); 
})
```

Comment: thanks so much both of you. both of your answers gave the same information and from there i could figure out how to get the guild owner id properly. much love <3